# How to change the label name dynamically in vs-tab using vue.js

Tags: vue.js

```
<vs-tab lable="Kid 1" >
<vs-tab lable="Kid 2" >
```

and so on...

I made the dynamically add kid and used this like

```
<vs-tab lable="Kid 1" v-for"(kid,index) in kids>
```

I mean this `lable="Kid{{index+1}}` but showing error plz help me out..

Comment: What kind of error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should replace your code to this:

```
<vs-tab :label="'Kid ' + (index + 1)" v-for"(kid,index) in kids">
```

Comment: @Freestyle09, this is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

And to complete the right answer from @webprogrammer don't forget: for a `v-for` you need to add a unique key, for instance : `:key="index"`